# SFDX CLI - v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory

Tags: salesforcedx

Recently I've been trying to automate certain upserts of information in our organization with a quick Powershell script. The problem we have encountered though is that the sfdx cli application runs out of memory in the process.

The script we're running is very simple so far:

```
## Authorize the org ##
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid $env:CONSUMER_KEY --username $env:HUB_USERNAME --jwtkeyfile $env:JWT_KEY_FILE -r "https://test.salesforce.com"

## Upload CSV ##
sfdx force:data:bulk:upsert -f "D:\export_data.csv" -s "MyObject__c" -i "MyKey__c" --json -u $env:HUB_USERNAME
```

And the file we're loading contains around 360k records.

I've verified that it is not my machine which runs out of memory (the quick memory fall is when the cli shuts down):

[image: Machine Memory]

And the error is as follows:

[image: CLI error]

Any ideas on how to move forward? Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: can you try after installing this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/increase-memory-limit    Command to run - npm install -g increase-memory-limit

Comment: How can you make sure it executes before the sfdx command does? I've tried executing it before calling the sfdx cli, but it doesn't work. I assume I would have to in some way force the actual cli to invoke it, but I don't know how.